# How to get Url after posting form data to server in Java?

Tags: java

I am posting some form data to a server which url is of the following type

http://myserver.com/redirect.php?query=student

The server after posting returns a webpage which is blank but the url is of the following format

http://myserver.com/studentinformation.php?std=student&age=20&result=pass

What I want to do is that I want to get above url query string e-g like std=student and age=20 and result=pass

I am using HttpUrlConnection in Java and I know how to send Get and Post request. But I don't know how to get that particular url after when you post to server and server returns such url. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. :)